# Is there a supported Mac Theme available?

Tags: themes, mac

The default themes in ubuntu like ambiance, radiance are good but old.

So I want a mac theme for my ubuntu 12.10.

I tried some mac themes but they were either not full supported or not good.

Some part of the themes are not working properly and the icon theme is almost perfect but there is no * icon in the top-right corner.

Anybody have any suggestions?